# Difference between だろうか and ではないだろうか

Tags: grammar, word-choice

In my opinion, they both share the same meaning of "~, isn't it". However, it seems that they cannot be used interchangeably. For example, in the following sentence, according to my mock exam textbook, ではないだろうか is correct for ＿＿ but not だろうか .

> ラブレターや海外からの絵葉書をメールで代用するのはおそらく無理 ＿＿。

Comment: +1 but I do wonder where you learned that the two shared the same meaning.  They do not.

Comment: I feel that だろうか has more a doubting feeling, whereas ではないだろうか emphasizes more that something is probably true.

Comment: 「ではないだろうか」は、「だろうか」よりも「だろう」のほうにより近いと思います。

Comment: Only ないだろうか means "~, isn't it".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the descending order of certainty:

- ～だろう = "I think (some clause)." The speaker thinks the clause is probably (or almost certainly) true.
- **～ではないだろうか** = "I think (some clause), isn't it?" The speaker thinks the clause is perhaps true, but he's less certain as compared to the first sentence.
- ～だろうか = "I wonder whether or not (some clause)." The speaker doesn't know if the clause is true or false. **You cannot add 恐らく to this sentence** because the speaker is totally unsure.
- ～ではないだろう = "I don't think (some clause)." The speaker thinks the clause is probably *not* true.

> - 彼は（恐らく）大丈夫だろう。 He must be okay.
> - 彼は（恐らく）大丈夫ではないだろうか。 I think he is okay.
> - 彼は大丈夫だろうか。 I wonder if he is okay. / I'm worried if he's okay.
> - 彼は（恐らく）大丈夫ではないだろう。 He must not be okay.

In the example sentence, the speaker is saying "It's *probably* impossible (無理) to use e-mails in place of ...", so 恐らく無理ではないだろうか is the correct phrase. 恐らく無理だろう is equally fine. The existence of the word 恐らく is what makes ～だろうか wrong. You can't usually say "I wonder if he is *probably* fine." in English, either.