# What is the correct question 何だろう or 何だろうか

Tags: questions, particle-か, grammar

How to ask a question with だろう in the correct way?
Should I add か in the end?

Like 何だろうか？
I saw a lot of examples and almost always guys omit か in the end. And just say 何だろう；いつだろう。。。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

～だろう forms a question that is mainly addressed to yourself. It's like "I wonder". If you are clearly requesting an answer from someone else, don't use it.

Next, か after だろう in a yes/no type question corresponds to English "whether/if", and it's mandatory. か in a wh-question (i.e., a question including いつ, だれ, 何, なぜ, etc) is purely optional, but is usually omitted especially in casual speech.

> - 彼は来るだろう**か**？ I wonder **if** he will come.
> - これは食べられるだろう**か**？ I wonder **if** I can eat this.

> - これは何だろう？  (I wonder,) What's this?
> - これは何だろうか？ (I wonder,) What's this?
> - どうしてだろう？ I wonder why.
> - どうしてだろうか？ I wonder why.

Related:

- [だろう in question context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62238/5010)
- [Difference between だろうか and ではないだろうか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34189/5010)
- [願わくばこのまま穏やかなままとはいかねぇもんだろうか meaning?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69057/5010)

Answer (score 0):

I think that generally you would only need/put the か in formal form such as ...ですか or ...ますか.
In casual speaking the か is rarely used at the end as you just use intonation to make it a question.